Angular load module providers with withModuleFederationPlugin
I am using Angular 15 with MFE.
In the shell webpack.config.js I have:
const {
  shareAll,
  withModuleFederationPlugin,
} = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");

const webpackConfig = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  shared: {
    ...shareAll({
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: "auto",
    }),
  },
});

module.exports = {
  ...webpackConfig,
  output: {
    ...webpackConfig.output,
    scriptType: "text/javascript",
  },
};

In the MFE webpack.config.js I have:
const { shareAll, withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'acquirer-web-mf-management',
  exposes: {
    './PlanningModule': './/src/app/planning/planning.module.ts'},
  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  }
});

I'm loading the MFE onto the shell like that:
 {
        path: 'planejamento',
        loadChildren: () =>
          loadRemoteModule({
            type: 'module',
            remoteEntry: `${environment.ACQUIRER_MF_MANAGEMENT}/remoteEntry.js`,
            exposedModule: './PlanningModule'
          }).then(m => m.PlanningModule)
      }

And in the MFE, the PlanningModule is like that:

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PlanningComponent,
    PlanningHeaderComponent,
    PlanningTabComponent,
    PlanningAdressComponent,
    PlanningReceiptComponent,
    StepperItemComponent,
    StepperComponent,
    PlanningSummaryComponent,
    PlanningOrderComponent,
    OrderListingTableComponent,
    CustomTabComponent,
    CustomSpinnerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgxMaskDirective,
    NgxMaskPipe,
    PlanningRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    PopoverModule,
    RadioModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    SharedModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    DataPickerModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature(
      fromPlanningReducer.planningFeatureKey,
      fromPlanningReducer.reducer,
    ),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([PlanningEffects]),
    NgxPermissionsModule.forChild(),
    MatTabsModule,
    MultiSelectModule,
    BadgeModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    CardModule,
    TimeFormatDirective,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useFactory: (handler: HttpBackend) => {
        console.log("na factory antes de carregar")
        let configService = new ConfigService(handler);
        waitFor(configService.loadConfig()).then(() => {
          console.log("na factory apos de carregar: ");
          return configService;
        });
      },
    },
    {
      provide: APP_CONFIG,
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => configService.getConfig(),
      deps: [ConfigService],
      multi: true
    }],
  exports: [SharedModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class PlanningModule {

  constructor() {
  }
}

That problem that I'm facing is the module's providers not been called.
The APP_CONFIG provide is not even available to the MFE itself.
Is it possible to share, or make them work using MFE with withModuleFederationPlugin and webpack.
